# Remove tax from certain Postcodes

Tags: checkout, tax, vat

There are some postcodes within countries that are VAT Exempt.
I am wondering if there is a way that in the checkout process, when the customer chooses their shipping address, to then remove the VAT from the totals.

I know there is the Tax Zones and Rates in admin but it doesnt appear to work the way i need it to

Comment: How are you trying to achieve this? Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Tried to use the Tax Zones and Rates adding a postcode in there and putting 0%, but that only seems to work when putting +0% and actually adding tax onto the totals.
Also looked at cart price rules and using the conditions sections where it allows you to select shipping postcodes etc, but you cant remove tax that way

Also looking at trying to pass config through stores config, using dynamic rows, not got very far with that way tho